# One-To-Many models and Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
#models.py

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Tags(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Article(TimeStampedMode):
    ...
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tags)
```

In Django admin, `tag` shows up as a HTML `<select multiple>`.
What I'm trying to do is:
A `Section` could have many `Tags`, and from `Article` I could pick a `Tags` from `Section`.
Also, it needs to be able to get a `Article`'s `Section`(via `tags.parent`?).

Currently this works. But, instead of `<select multiple>`, `Tags` shows up as a `<input>` instead of a `<select multiple>`. 
What I want is for both `Tags` and `Section` appear as `<select multiple>`.

edit:

What I want is:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your description is confusing; you say it both works as a select multiple and it doesn't work because it gives an input. Which is it?

Comment: I'd like both to be `<select multiple>` on the admin page of `Article`.

Comment: Both what? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry. I have uploaded a image to elaborate more, please see the now updated question.

Comment: The screenshot you added is to create a Tag, right? If so, if you want the name to be a select box, you need to tell the model what is the source of possible names, e.g. with a ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your need correctly. But according to your image, you need `Section` and `Tags` are set `One-To-Many field` in `Article`.

```
#models.py

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class TagName(models.Model):
     tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    name = models.ForeignKey(TagName)

class Article(TimeStampedMode):
    ...
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tags)
```

I think this method is more useful and matching with your need.

screenshot of the given model code:

[this is Article page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOOlZ.png)

[go into tag and you can see select multiple for both fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gO8.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By using a foreign key to define the relationship, you're limiting the number of Tags an Article may have to 1. For an Article to have more than one Tag, you'll want to use a ManyToMany relationship.

Read more on many-to-many relationships with Django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

The Django admin site will automatically use a select if you're using a foreign key relationship, or a multi-select if you're using a many-to-many relationship.

Here's what a many-to-many will look like from Article to Tags:

```
class Article(TimeStampedMode):
    ...
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```